# Prove a Set is Closed Under Addition

Tags: linear-algebra

How would you prove that the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose coordinates $x, y, z,$ satisfy the the equation

$$6x - 2y - 4z =0$$

is closed under vector addition?

I know that the set only contains elements where $x = y = z$, but how would that translate into a proof that the set is closed under addition?

Comment: No, it contains all elements of the form (s, 3s-2t ,t)

Comment: "I know that the set only contains elements where x=y=z"  No, you don't.  Let $y=0; z=6;x = 4$.

Comment: I don't think looking at an answer for a question like this will help that much.  You just need to see how the general structure of a proof would look, and then fill in the details.  If you can correctly set up the argument, this is something that will "prove itself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that two vectors $\vec v=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $\vec w=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are both in the set described. Then
$$6x_1 - 2y_1 - 4z_1 =0$$
$$6x_2 - 2y_2 - 4z_2 =0$$
and so, by adding these two equations,
$$6(x_1+x_2) - 2(y_1+y_2) - 4(z_1+z_2) =0$$
which implies that the vector $\vec v+\vec w=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,z_1+z_2)$ is also in the described set. Thus, since $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ being in the set implies that $\vec v+\vec w$ is also in the set, it is closed under vector addition. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

suppose that $(x,y,z),(a,b,c)$ satisfy the equation.

Then $(x-2y-4z)+(a-2b-4c)=0$, but then $(x+a)-2(y+b)-4(z+c)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $6x - 2y - 4z =0$ and $6a - 2b - 4c =0$.

We know $(x, y,z) + (a,b,c) = (x+a, y+ b, z+c)$

So what does $6(x+a) - 2(y+b) - 4(z + c)$ equal?